# Change CSS class in Wayfinder MODx menu dependent on page template

Tags: css, menu, navigation, modx, wayfinder

I've got a dropdown menu created with Wayfinder in MODx. Basically I'm trying to style specific page links in the dropdown, depending on which template the specific page is using.

So fx. if a page is using template "A", its link in the dropdown gets the class A - and class "A" can be styled.

How would you do this?

I would also like to order the page links in the dropdown, according to their page's template.

Thanks!

Edit:

Basically I'm trying to style specific page links in the dropdown, depending on a template variable I've set up. I've got a TV called [*status*] which can be set to 1 of 3 radio options when editing a page.

So fx. if a page's [*status*] is set to "A", its link in the dropdown gets the class A - and class "A" can be styled.

Answer (score 1):

Add class to body tag:

```
<body class="template-[[*template]]">
```

And then just use it in css like:

```
.my_wayfinder_menu {
    /* common style */
} 
.template-5 .my_wayfinder_menu {
    /* only for template with id 5 */
}
```

Comment: The menu is visible across the whole site. This would only work if it was on a specific page right? 

Or what body tag do you mean?

Comment: It works on specific pages assigned to a certain template which contains that tag body specified in the answer.

Comment: But, it shoudn't work on specific pages, it should work "globally" in the dropdown menu. 

Maybe this description is more accurate:

Basically I'm trying to style specific page links in the dropdown, depending on a template variable I've set up. I've got a TV called [*status*] which can be set to 1 of 3 radio options when editing a page. 

So fx. if a page's [*status*] is set to "A", its link in the dropdown gets the class A - and class "A" can be styled.

Comment: ok, how about `<body class="id-[[*id]] template-[[*template]] tv-[[*status]]">`? it work on specific pages with specific template and  specific tv.